# unexplained reputation loss

Tags: support, reputation

My rep activity for today says -15, yet the detailed list below the stats only shows a single -1, ditto on the [extended version](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/108/matt-wilkie?tab=reputation). Why don't they match?

[image]

I'm more curious than concerned.

Comment: probably someone changed an accepted answer from one of yours (got the rep days ago) to someone else's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably someone changed an accepted answer from one of yours (got the rep days ago) to someone else's.

Comment: You're right. I tracked it down and this is what happened, thanks for clearing that up. FWIW I think it's a bug that this kind of event isn't reported in the reputation log.