# Tracking reputation loss

Tags: support, reputation

A few minutes ago I saw on my profile page that the reputation tab said `-15`. But when I go to that tab, the `-15` isn't reflected anywhere (nor is it listed in the /reputation list), even though the reputation was removed from my score. I do have the checkmark next to "show removed posts."

I would expect this was an un-accept, and if so, I'd love to know which one it was (maybe I posted a bad answer that was accepted at the time, and since has received a better answer - I can learn from that too!).

But there doesn't seem to be a way to figure out where this happened. This seems related to this question:

[unexplained reputation loss](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85180/unexplained-reputation-loss)

But the answer there doesn't explain why it isn't shown in the rep list (and I think it is also from before the changes to rep calcs). I see unaccepts in my rep timeline that definitely do show `-15`, so I'm not sure what the difference may be...

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, actually. It's fine if it's an unaccept, but shouldn't it be listed in my reputation events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [T]he answer there doesn't explain why it isn't shown in the rep list[.]

Somebody accepted one of your answers **today** and unaccepted it after you had already seen the `+15` change in your profile.

Unaccepting an answer the same day it got accepted doesn't create a second entry on your reputation page; it just removes the previous entry.

Comment: That seems strange to me. Why abolish all evidence of an accept then unaccept, when the opposite history remains intact (even when it occurs during the same minute)? http://i.stack.imgur.com/LwYRs.png Do you have a source that confirms the behavior you suggest is documented, much less by design?

Comment: Quick accept/unaccepts shouldn't show in the rep history at all, should they? Or is it that they don't repeat? I remember there was a request to change that behavior after people were seeing 5 accept/unaccepts in a row

Comment: @Ben did you look at the image I posted in my comment? Perhaps I should add that to the question as a counter-example. It doesn't make sense to me that accept -> unaccept would disappear but unaccept -> accept would be maintained.

Comment: Saw that after posting. I guess it does pop up. Not sure what happened then.

Comment: I guess the intention was to not clutter up the reputation history in case somebody changed his mind quickly. Similarly, un(up|down)votes aren't displayed either if the unvote happened fast enough. I'd like to see this changed though. The rep history could still get cleaned up a couple of days later. @BenBrocka: The screenshot displays a **reaccept**. That seems to be different.